# How to embed a youtube channel in my site

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, youtube, sharepoint-2013

I have a url like: https://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Without user, is it possible to embed a channel to show the latest videos in my webpage using IFRAME?? if possible how???

I saw with user like:

```
<iframe width="600" height="340" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-   results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It works but without user how can i embed??

Comment: what do you mean by "without user"? post more details about what you want like what you already have, the expected result...this will help us to help you.

Comment: as my link has no user:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

this link has no 'user/'.

Comment: You might want to checkout this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: you cannot simply add URL in this case because it will throw an error about `X-Frame-Options` header set to `sameorigin`...you can try to change this option [Look this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72987/is-there-a-way-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-or-at-least-modify-it)

Answer (score 1):

YouTube provides an RSS feed for each channel: `https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id={{{channel_id_here}}}`, so you could make a script that check this RSS feed periodically and updates your database.

The easiest way to get this RSS feed URL is probably to give the channel's URL to a feed aggregator: for instance, Vsauce's feed is https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC6nSFpj9HTCZ5t-N3Rm3-HA.